# Gluing together files in multiple, nested subdirectories in bash

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, rename, batch-rename

I have a set of directories that looks like this:

```
www.me.com/a/b/c/file.csv
www.you.com/a/b/c/d/e/file.csv
www.us.com/a/file.csv
```

In bash, I'm attempting to rename the file with the directory path:

```
www.me.com/a/b/c/www.me.comabcfile.csv
www.you.com/a/b/c/d/e/www.you.comabcdefile.csv
www.us.com/a/www.us.comafile.csv
```

The sequence I've tried is:

```
rename 's/(.*)\//$1\/$1/' *
```

This does not have the desired outcome, instead creating monstrously large file names.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since this is also tagged `zsh`: `autoload zmv; zmv -nv '(**/)(file.csv)' '$1${1//\/}$2'`.       
It uses a parameter expansion to strip out the slashes from the new file name; you can probably do something similar in `bash`.    
BTW, the `-n` option in `zmv` is for a dry run, remove it to actually rename the files.

Comment: @Gairfowl that's amazing. Thank you - I run zsh on my Mac as the default and that's wonderful. Had no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the job doesn't seem performance-relevant, we can take our time and do it in a loop for better readability:

```
#!/bin/bash

FN="file.csv"

while read FP; do
  test -f "$FP" || continue
  D=$(dirname "$FP")
  NN=$(echo "$D" | sed 's#^\.##; s#/##g')"$FN"
  mv -v "$FP" "$D/$NN"
done < <(find . -name "$FN")
```